# Improving the mesh and memory usage of Comsol Multiphysics 3.5?

Tags: c, matlab

How can I increase the mesh size of Comsol without increasing the memory of my system?
My system memory is 32 GB but I cannot simulate my problem because it needs a lot of memory.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know how you can solve it. But I'm fairly sure that with the limited amount of information you've given us we can't help either. If this is a programming problem to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the mesh size. Increasing the mesh size cause decreasing the amount of memory that is needed for simulation. With increasing the mesh size you can solve huge problems with less memory. There is no other way for decreasing the amount of memory that you need for simulation; because you don't write any program and all things done automatically in COMSOL.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to say "increase"?

Comment: @Bart Yes I sure. Suppose you have cubic simulation domain with 100 nm in each axis; if the mesh size is 1nm you have 1000000 computation points. if you select 2 nm mesh size you have just 125000 computation points.

Comment: I would call that a decrease rather. A decrease of mesh density. An increase of mesh size suggests to me rather the opposite of what you're saying. Therefor my confusion. :)

Comment: Hi, do you also know what to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550076/simulation-of-effect-of-heated-resistance-on-temperature-distribution-in-laminar?noredirect=1#comment74163876_43550076